# Creating temporary files in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have an app hosted @ Heroku. The app depends on some feeds which are fetched using a socket listener. The socket listener gets one line of XML per second. Once I detect the end of file signal from the listener, I upload the file to Amazon S3 servers. But, until the end of file signal is received, is it possible to save the file content as a temporary file in Heroku?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You may be able to use [the `#{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/` directory](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem) or `Rails.root.join('tmp').to_s`:

> **Aspen & Bamboo**
>   [...]
>   There are two directories that are writeable: `./tmp` and `./log` (under your application root).
>   [...]
>
> **Cedar**
>   Cedar offers an ephemeral writeable filesystem. You can write out to disk anywhere you would like. Your changes will be lost on dyno restart and spin-up.

`RAILS_ROOT` is for older Rails versions, `Rails.root` is for newer versions.

You can't depend on anything surviving across requests of course, there's no guarantee that you'll even be working with the same dyno.

As long as you stay within the same process or request, `Rails.root.join('tmp')` should be usable. If you need the temporary data to survive across requests or processes then you're better off using something else (such as MongoDB or PostgreSQL) as a collecting ground for your data on its way to S3.

---

Thanks to [Benjamin Wheeler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308190/benjamin-wheeler) for the heads up about the `RAILS_ROOT` to `Rails.root` change.

Comment: @satya: I'd use a database of some sort so that nothing will be lost if something goes wrong.

Comment: +1 @mu is too short I was surprised to notice that files where actually getting uploaded. This clarifies.

Comment: FYI, the updated Rails 4 way to do this is Rails.root, not RAILS_ROOT: eg, "#{Rails.root}/tmp/"

Answer (score 16):

The [documentation on Heroku's read-only file system](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem) explains that you can use `#{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp` but doesn't give any examples for generating a temporary filename. This will guarantee uniqueness of the filename:

```
prefix = 'mydata'
suffix = '.xml'
Tempfile.new [prefix, suffix], "#{Rails.root}/tmp"
```

Note that "there is no guarantee that this file will be there on subsequent requests (although it might be), so this should not be used for any kind of permanent storage."

Comment: it wouldn't hurt to say: Rails.root.join('tmp')

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem is the latest link to Heroku's information on filesystems. It's not incredibly helpful to this question though.

Answer (score 1):

With the newer [Heroku-16](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-16-stack) stack, you are able to write to both the root **and** to `/tmp`

Try writing to root with

```
f = File.new("filename.txt", 'w')
f << "hi there"
f.close

Dir.entries(Dir.pwd) # see your newly created file
```

Or to `/tmp` with

```
f = File.new("tmp/filename.txt", 'w')
f << "hi there"
f.close

Dir.entries(Dir.pwd.to_s + ("/tmp"))
```

You will see your new file among those listed in both cases

Also try running `heroku restart` to see your newly created files disappear! This is expected, as heroku storage is ephemeral (will be deleted when the app restarts) - so don't rely on it for anything more than (very) temporary storage