# upload an RMagick-generated file from Heroku to Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, heroku, amazon-s3, image-uploading

I am creating a Rails app which is hosted on Heroku and that allows the user to generate animated GIFs on the fly based on an original JPG that's hosted somewhere in the web (think of it as a crop-resize app). I tried Paperclip but, AFAIK, it does not handle dynamically-generated files. I am using the `aws-sdk` gem and this is a code snippet of my controller:

```
im = Magick::Image.read(@animation.url).first

fr1 = im.crop(@animation.x1,@animation.y1,@animation.width,@animation.height,true)
str1 = fr1.to_blob
fr2 = im.crop(@animation.x2,@animation.y2,@animation.width,@animation.height,true)
str2 = fr2.to_blob

list = Magick::ImageList.new
list.from_blob(str1)
list.from_blob(str2)
list.delay = @animation.delay
list.iterations = 0
```

That is for the basic creation of a two-frame animation. RMagick can generate a GIF in my development computer with these lines:

```
list.write("#{Rails.public_path}/images/" + @animation.filename)
```

I tried uploading the `list` structure to S3:

```
# upload to Amazon S3
s3 = AWS::S3.new
bucket = s3.buckets['mybucket']
obj = bucket.objects[@animation.filename]
obj.write(:single_request => true, :content_type  => 'image/gif', :data => list)
```

But I don't have a `size` method in `RMagick::ImageList` that I can use to specify that. I tried "precompiling" the GIF into another `RMagick::Image`:

```
anim = Magick::Image.new(@animation.width, @animation.height)
anim.format = "GIF"
list.write(anim)
```

But Rails crashes with a segmentation fault:

```
/path/to/my_controller.rb:103: [BUG] Segmentation fault ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]
Abort trap: 6
```

Line 103 corresponds to `list.write(anim)`.

So right now I have no idea how to do this and would appreciate any help I receive.

Comment: I would focus on the segfault you get when outputting the image, there's no obvious reason I can think of for that to happen.  Can you run your code from the console and see what happens?

Comment: Thanks. I added the segfault output in the rails console (actually the `rails server` console not the `rails console` console).

Comment: What line is #103 in the code above?  Is it the write statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this project is hosted in Heroku I cannot use the filesystem so that is why I was trying to do everything via code. I found that Heroku does have a temporary-writable folder: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem

This works just fine in my case since I don't need the file after this request.

The resulting code:

```
im = Magick::Image.read(@animation.url).first

fr1 = im.crop(@animation.x1,@animation.y1,@animation.width,@animation.height,true)
fr2 = im.crop(@animation.x2,@animation.y2,@animation.width,@animation.height,true)

list = Magick::ImageList.new
list << fr1
list << fr2
list.delay = @animation.delay
list.iterations = 0

# gotta packet the file
list.write("#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{@animation.filename}.gif")

# upload to Amazon S3
s3 = AWS::S3.new
bucket = s3.buckets['mybucket']
obj = bucket.objects[@animation.filename]
obj.write(:file => "#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{@animation.filename}.gif")
```

It would be interesting to know if a non-filesystem-writing solution is possible.

Comment: just pointing out that there's been an "non-filesystem-writing" solution here for a while which also happens to be a much more concise answer. You may want to change the official answer to this question. But, I'm biased. ;)

Answer (score 10):

As per @mga's request in his answer to his original question...

a non-filesystem based approach is pretty simple

```
rm_image = Magick::Image.from_blob(params[:image][:datafile].read)[0]
  # [0] because from_blob returns an array
  # the blob, presumably, can have multiple images data in it
a_thumbnail = rm_image.resize_to_fit(150, 150)
  # just as an example of doing *something* with it before writing
s3_bucket.objects['my_thumbnail.jpg'].write(a_thumbnail.to_blob, {:acl=>:public_read})
```

Voila! reading an uploaded file, manipulating it with RMagick, and writing it to s3 without ever touching the filesystem.

Comment: Do you have any idea how you do this from a montage? so `montage = Magick::List.new(list).montage` and then write montage straight to S3? `montage` at this point has not been written to the file system, so I'm not sure what it even is at this point.

Comment: alas no, I haven't used montages so can't comment on them.

Comment: how about animated GIFs as stated in the question?

Comment: any image jpg/png/gif is ultimately a blob (Binary Large Object). You make or edit your animated gif then get the blob of it and do the same thing as with the jpg in my example. The to_blob method doesn't make any mention of caring what type of image you're working with beyond letting you specify a type of blob to create. In short. Animated or not, the handling (for the task of shoving it on s3) *should* be the same.

Comment: well then why not answer in such a way that conforms to the question: generate an animated gif based on a jpeg provided? my answer addresses this. may be less "elegant" but does the job

Comment: I was answering the subject of the question (how to upload to s3 from heroku) and the problem that the accepted answer failed to address (doing it without the filesystem) the jpg->gif conversion is irrelevant to the question of uploading to s3 from heroku and should be a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

I am updating this answer for AWS SDK Version 2 which should be:

```
rm_image = Magick::Image.from_blob(params[:image][:datafile].read)[0]
  # [0] because from_blob returns an array
  # the blob, presumably, can have multiple images data in it
a_thumbnail = rm_image.resize_to_fit(150, 150)
  # just as an example of doing *something* with it before writing

s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new
bucket = s3.bucket('mybucket')
obj = bucket.object('filename')
obj.put(body: background.to_blob)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a few things going on here.  First, the documentation for RMagick is sub-par, and its easy to get side-tracked.  The code you're using to generate the gif can be a little simpler.  I cooked up a very contrived example here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'RMagick'

# read in source file
im = Magick::Image.read('foo.jpg').first

# make two slightly different frames
fr1 = im.crop(0, 100, 300, 300, true)
fr2 = im.crop(0, 200, 300, 300, true)

# create an ImageList
list = Magick::ImageList.new

# add our images to it
list << fr1
list << fr2

# set some basic values
list.delay = 100
list.iterations = 0

# write out an animated gif to the filesystem
list.write("foo.gif")
```

This code works -- it reads in a jpg I have locally, and writes out a 2-frame animation.  Obviously I've hardcoded some values here, but there's no reason this shouldn't work for you, although I am running ruby 1.9.2 and probably a different version of RMagick, but this is basic code.

The second issue is totally unrelated -- is it possible to upload an image generated in IM to S3 without actually hitting the filesystem?  Basically, will this ever work:

```
obj.write(:single_request => true, :content_type  => 'image/gif', :data => list)
```

I'm not sure if it is or not.  I experimented with calling `list.to_blob`, but it only outputs the first frame, and it's as a JPG, although I didn't spend much time on it. You might be able to fool `list.write` into outputting somewhere, but rather than going down that road, I would personally just output the file unless that is impossible for some reason.

Comment: it is indeed impossible since I am using Heroku and you can't do that (unless someone knows how to create some sort of temp file there)... I tried most of what you suggest and had those results... I will try the suggested variation on adding to the list which uses fewer `.to_blob` and `.from_blob` which might be the reason I get segfaults

Comment: As I understand it, you can create tmp files on Heroku: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661395/creating-temporary-files-in-heroku and http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem --  but I have not used it personally.

Comment: working on that as we speak... getting a general 500 error... using `list.write("#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{@animation.filename}.gif")` and then `obj.write(:file => "#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{@animation.filename}.gif")` to upload to S3... it works in my machine but not in Heroku... thanks

Comment: ok so I nailed it by using that `tmp`! will add an answer with what I did