# Processing attachments with Heroku and Mailgun Routes

Tags: design-patterns, heroku, mailgun

My webapp is a Ruby on Rails application deployed to Heroku.

I use Mailgun Routes to forward email to my web application. The documentation for Mailgun Routes is here http://documentation.mailgun.net/user_manual.html#um-routes.

Basically Mailgun Routes POSTs stuff like subject, body, senders etc as HTTP parameters. Attachments are POSTed as file uploads encoded in multipart/form-data. In the controller, they show up as an UploadedFile (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html).

In the controller, I proceed to upload the attachment(s) to S3.

However if there are large attachments or many attachments, the request will time out (Heroku's infamous H12 error).

I tried using a background worker (delayed job) but ran into these issues

- Sending the entire UploadedFile object or UploadedFile.tempfile to the background worker leads to unreliable behavior (delayed job doesn't play nice with large objects such as Model instances)
- Sending the path to the tempfile and trying to open it doesn't work since tempfiles are accessible only to the dyno they are on (tempfile is stored in the web worker dyno and access to it is tried from the background worker dyno which fails - [Creating temporary files in Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661395/creating-temporary-files-in-heroku))

Any clever ideas on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I've just come across similar problems using Mailgun's Routes feature. The answer to the problem seems to be to use their 'Store' feature which was released later in 2013. Wish I'd come across this before integrating the Routes feature, as the approach to using Store is quite different.