# Ruby, heroku: Get the URL of a temporary file (binary)

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having trouble getting the URL of a temp file I've created. The objective of my controller called with ajax is to generate a PDF in a temporary dir that is cleaned each time dynos start, then return JSON with the URL of the file. The JavaScript waiting for the JSON will then call `window.location.href` to download the PDF.

I've done all I think of, but it's not working. I've heard that Heroku has a temporary directory cleaned each time dynos are started (cf [creating-temporary-files-in-heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661395/creating-temporary-files-in-heroku)). But that post is 2 years old and is talking about `RAILS_ROOT` that does not exist anymore. So I'm using `Rails.root.join('app', 'tmp')`

Here is my controller function:

```
def print_a
  pdf = render_to_string :pdf => params[:name],
    :template => "prints/printA.pdf.html.erb",
    :layout => nil

  temp_dir = Rails.root.join('app','tmp')
  Dir.mkdir(temp_dir) unless Dir.exists?(temp_dir)
  @tempfile = Tempfile.new [params[:name], '.pdf'], temp_dir
  @tempurl = "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port.sub(/:80$/,"")}/tmp/#{File.basename(@tempfile.path)}"
  File.open(@tempfile.path, 'wb') do |file|
      file << pdf
  end

  render "prints/printA.rabl"
end
```

The JSON is rendered via `prints/printA.rabl`:

```
node(:tempurl) { @tempurl }
node(:tempfile) { @tempfile.path }
```

I'm using `tempfile` to see if the dir is good. It gives:

`/home/alain/Projects/Heroku/pj/app/tmp/_20131022-4464-alrmkb.pdf`

The real value important for the JavaScript is `tempurl`:

`http://0.0.0.0:5000/tmp/_20131022-4464-alrmkb.pdf`

And if I visit this `tempurl`, I get this error:

`No route matches [GET] "/tmp/_20131022-4464-alrmkb.pdf"`

Can anyone help me get it to work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't point to the tmp folder. simple as that.

what you can do is

a) put a tmp folder in your public folder, because public is served by the http server

b) stream the file through some controller action in your rails application