# Creating a file in memory because Heroku does not allow filesystem access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have an `Experiment` model with the fields -

- `start_date`
- `end_date`
- `results` - a CSV dump of results from the experiment. Attachment managed via Paperclip and stored remotely on Amazon S3

I'm able to generate the CSV contents of the `results` attachment in memory, but since Heroku has no filesystem access, I can't physically write the file to disk and transfer it to Amazon S3.

Is there a way around this? Perhaps a way to virtually create a file in memory and then move it over to a remote host like S3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ./tmp directory to create a temporary file. Please checkout this question for more details:

[Creating temporary files in Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661395/creating-temporary-files-in-heroku)