# Creating Files In Heroku Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been trying to sort out a problem for quite sometime now. I am using Rails 5 and have my site on production. I am trying to find a way to create a file on Users desktop or any place accessible to the user locally. The code below works perfectly fine in localhost but for some strange reason I can seem to make it work on my heroku deployed application.

I have also tried to public\synonyms.txt as a path which is included in the application package and also works in localhost but the same problem persists in my heroku deployed app.

I read on some of the other stackoverflow questions that heroku has an ephemeral filesystem. But isn't there any way to create file on the system itself so that the file does not gets wiped out.

```
<%
  my_file = File.open(ENV['HOME']+"/Desktop/synonyms.txt", "w")
  @solrs.each do |solr|
    my_file.write(solr.disease.to_s + "," + solr.synonym.to_s + "\n") 
   end
   my_file.close()
%>
```

Any suggestions to fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: As you said, the Heroku filesystem is ephemeral, so any changes to the filesystem whilst the dyno is running only last until that dyno is shut down or restarted. You can read more here and check the documentation for handling uploads to s3 for example. https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted

Comment: Thanks Jose! Yes, I understand this but what I don't get is that I am not trying to make a file in the heroku app directory. I am trying to make a file on the user system (local), is there no way to work around with that? thanks

Comment: Ah, I don't think you can create a file on an user's filesystem. It works for you in local because the "local filesystem" is where the app is running, but this is not the case when you deploy the app to heroku.

Comment: Ah Okay! :((( - thanks thou

Comment: Hi, Just a quick addon to my previous question. Is there a way to store the file temporary in heroku app directory, without restarting dyno. As with the code above it's not even making a temporary file(with path public\synonyms.txt)? Any idea?

Comment: Forgot to add...I've also tried this for the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661395/creating-temporary-files-in-heroku:  my_file = File.open("#{Rails.root}/tmp/synonyms.txt", "w")

Comment: You can't access the users file system from a remote server, but you can send a file to them to download via the same mechanism you'd download a file from the internet anywhere else. They click the link, and get a "download" prompt. There's an article [here](https://www.devroom.io/2007/07/02/how-to-force-data-to-be-downloaded-as-a-file-from-your-rails-app/) that might help if this is sufficient